# Question over group isomorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ and $H$ be two groups, and denote the direct product, $G \times H$, by K.

The direct product is defined as: Let $(S, \bigodot$) and $(B, \bullet)$ be groups with the respective operation. Then $S \times B$, the direct product $\diamond$, is $(s_1, b_1) \diamond (s_2, b_2) = (s_1 \bigodot s_2, b_1 \bullet b_2)$.

Back to the problem. Let $H'$ be the subset of $K$ consisting of all ordered pairs $(e, h)$. $e$ is obviously the identity element of $G$ and $h$ is any element of $H$. Prove that $H'$ is a subroup of $K$ and that it is isomorphic to $H$ ($H'\cong H$).

So I know that I need to construct an explicit isomorphism to show that $H' \cong H$ and to show it actually is an isomorphism

Answer (score 1):

Let $\phi:H^\prime\to H$ be $\phi(e,h)=h$. Then 
$$
\phi((e,h_1)\diamond(e,h_2))=\phi(e\odot e,h_1\bullet h_2)=\phi(e,h_1\bullet h_2)=h_1\bullet h_2=\phi(e,h_1)\bullet\phi(e,h_2)
$$
so $\phi$ is a homomorphism.

To see that $\phi$ is injective, suppose $\phi(e,h_1)=\phi(e,h_2)$. Then $h_1=h_2$ so $(e,h_1)=(e,h_2)$. Hence $\phi$ is injective.

To see that $\phi$ is surjective, suppose $h\in H$. Then $\phi(e,h)=h$ so $\phi$ is surjective.

This shows that $\phi$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: Ah this makes sense. How would I prove it is a subgroup. I know I need to show Associativity (given essentially), identity element, and that every element needs to have an inverse and closure.

I know how to show the identity element, but how do I show the 2 other properties?

Comment: @RoyM. See http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/One-Step_Subgroup_Test